# Tkinter widget layout is wrong?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been putting a menu together using Tkinter with Python 2.7. It works functionally, but the layout is very messy. I'm usng the .grid() method to organise the widgets, but they are interfering with each other, so my listbox widget is taller than the buttons so they get spaced apart etc. What can I do to resolve this? 
The result I'm getting is shown here:

[image]

**With what I'm trying to achieve drawn out here:**

[image]

This is my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test")

command = []
class button():
    def __init__(self, root, text_in, x, y, command):
        self.text = text_in
        self.pressed = False
        self.button = tk.Button(root, text=text_in, width = 15, height = 5, command = lambda: add_to_command(self.text))
        self.button.grid(row=x, column = y)

def add_to_command(word):
    command.append(word)
    command.append(' ')
def print_command(command, command_line):
    if command_line.get():
        command = command_line.get()
    else:
        command = ''.join(command)
    print command

button1 = button(root, "1", 0, 1, command)
button2 = button(root, "2", 0, 2, command)
button3 = button(root, "3", 1, 1, command)
button4 = button(root, "4", 1, 2, command)
button5 = button(root, "5", 2, 1, command)
button6 = button(root, "6", 2, 2, command)
button7 = button(root, "7", 3, 1, command)
button8 = button(root, "8", 3, 2, command)
command_line = tk.Entry(root, width = 100, takefocus=1)
command_line.grid(row = 0,column = 3, padx = 10)
go_button = tk.Button(root, text="Enter", width = 15, height = 5, command = lambda: print_command(command, command_line))
go_button.grid(row=0, column=5)

list_box = tk.Listbox(root)
list_box.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
list_box.insert(0, "ENTRY 1")
list_box.insert(1, "ENTRY 2")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would suggest a frame on the left for the buttons, and a frame on the right for the entry widget and the listbox. You can then layout each section independently of the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell the grid to let (force) a widget to take up multiple rows/columns with the `columnspan` argument to `grid()`, i.e.:

```
...
list_box.grid(row=1, column=3, rowspan=3)
...
```

That will tell your `list_box` to cover (up to) three rows (if there's more space than the widget, you may need to `anchor` it to the (N)orth + (S)outh to stretch over available space) `columnspan` works in the same way.

As a note, spans anchor from the top-left; `row=1, column=3` with a `rowspan` and `columnspan` of 3 each will take up rows 1-3 and columns 3-5.